# matchedGeometryEffect doesn't work with PageTabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

```
@Namespace var ns

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.black)
            TabView {
                ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                    Text("item \(i)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: i, in: ns)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))

        }
    }
```

When I tried to give each TabView item an effect id, it complains `Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<Int, ID>(first: 0, second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 180)) have isSource: true, results are undefined.`

What's the correct way to assign a `matchedGeometryEffect` id to items in PageTabView so that I can zoom in and out with transition like the iOS photos app?

Or is it a bug of SwiftUI?

Comment: From my experience, matchedGeometryEffect does not do anything in most cases I think it has some issues to acutely be useful.

Comment: Looks like `PageTabViewStyle` specific bug.

Comment: It's the TabView. You can create your own TabView easily. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496023/adding-animation-to-tabviews-in-swiftui-when-switching-between-tabs